# branching in mkifs script files in QNX

Tags: build, rtos, qnx

Is it possible to add branching in the scripts that are being used to generate the image using the mkifs utility. I'm trying to read a file file and based on its contents branch the execution of the drivers in the script. 
Is such thing possible in the mkifs utility?

```
[+script] .script = {
    PATH=...
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
    display_msg myBoot
    TESTVAL=`cat /config/test.dat`
    TESTLEN={#TESTVAL}
    if["$TESTLEN" = 10]
        #start myDriver1
    else
        #start myDriver2
    ...
    ...
}
```

I'm getting an error that "cat: /config/test.dat: No such file or directory".

I guess i can create a application which spawns the drivers instead of doing this way. But was just wondering why is this not possible in the current way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have seen, This seems not possible.

So i have written a separate application,
Which will check the conditions for me and spawn the needed drivers.

and removed the drivers from the script and replaced them with the new application.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible.
the typical solution is to put that sort of logic into an inlined shell script and execute or fork the shell script.